# jQuery calendar and ajax button click - PHP jQuery BS-Calendar Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a script that will call the add button and there are three fields - Name (select box that is driven from db), Percentage and Calendar.

The script runs fine but I have problem with the calendar function.

The calendar is not working on the first button click (Add Author).

The second row calendar gets active when the third row is triggered. And it goes on.

If you check my fiddle code you will understand. 
http://jsfiddle.net/8PduS/5/

In other words, first time when i click the add row button, the second row calendar is not working. When I again click the add row button (i.e third row) the second row gets active with the calendar.

Where did I went wrong.

## Partial Code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var i=1;
    $("#add_row").click(function(){

    $('#addr'+i).html("<td>"+ (i+1) +"</td>");
    var selectClone = $('select:first').clone(true);  
    $('#datepicker.input-daterange').datepicker({
    format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
    todayBtn: "linked",
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true
    });

    $('#addr'+i).html("<td>"+ (i+1) +"</td><td><select name='name"+i+"' class='form-control input-md'>"+ selectClone.html() +"</select></td><td><input name='percent"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='Percent' class='form-control input-md'/></td><td><div class='input-daterange input-group' id='datepicker'><input required type='text' class='form-control' id='pa_start"+i+"' name='pa_start"+i+"' /></div></td>");
    $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr'+(i+1)+'"></tr>');
    i++; 
    });
    });
    </script>
```

Thanks,
Kimz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to intialise the datepicker when you append a new one to the DOM:

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8PduS/6/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    initDatePicker();
    var counter = 1;
    $("#add_row").click(function () {
        new_elem = $("#addr_template").clone().appendTo("#container tbody").show().attr("id", "addr" + counter);
        counter += 1;
        initDatePicker();
    });

    function initDatePicker() {
        $('#datepicker.input-daterange').datepicker({
            format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
            todayBtn: "linked",
            autoclose: true,
            todayHighlight: true
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: wow. excellent. thanks .. this worked. waiting for 6 more mins to mark your answer as my choice.

Comment: thanks a ton. this is what i need. perfect.. i will mark it as my chosen answer for sure..